# Migrating trigger from Oracle 11g to Postgresql 8.4

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, postgresql-8.4, triggers

My trigger in Oracle looks like this…

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example$example
    BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON example
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
            example$
        VALUES
            (
            :old.key,
            :old.name,
            :old.describe
            seq.nextVal
            );
    END;
```

I thought I could simply translate to Postgresql with this…

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example$example
    BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON example
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
            example$
        VALUES
            (
            OLD.key,
            OLD.name,
            OLD.describe,
            NEXTVAL('seq')
            );
    END;
```

I'm getting an error at the end of the INSERT statement.
Are there no anonymous blocks in Postgresql? Do I have to put this in a function? If so, what is the return value of the function? NULL?

**EDIT:**

So I'm now trying this…

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example$trigger()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $func$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
            example$
            (
            key,
            name,
            describe,
            seq
            )
        VALUES
            (
            OLD.key,
            OLD.name,
            OLD.describe,
            NEXTVAL('seq')
            );
    END
    $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql 


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example$trigger
    AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON example
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE example$trigger;
```

The function compiles with no errors by the trigger reports…

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRIGGER"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example$trigger
                          ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "TRIGGER"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 19
```

Comment: Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html Also: why would you migrate to Postgres 8.4? 8.4 is already end-of-life and no longer supported

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is why I've learned to hate stackoverflow.  The best anyone can do to help is tell me RTFM, as if I hadn't already done that.

Comment: a_horse didn't ask how you felt about SO, but why you want to migrate to an outdated version of Postgres. A valid question, looks like a big mistake. Also, the question should provide some explanation what the trigger is supposed to do. I can guess, but I shouldn't have to. And the general public might not be as experienced.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any sign that you read the manual. There are several examples in the link I provided that *clearly* show that triggers are different in Postgres - including the fact that you first create a function and the `create trigger` references that function.

Answer (score 5):

Triggers in Postgres don't provide trigger code directly, but call a **trigger function**, which can be called from any number of triggers, though often they are customized for one particular event on one particular table.

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_some_tbl_foo()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO some_tbl(key, name, describe)   -- or some_other_tbl?
VALUES (OLD.key, OLD.name, OLD.describe);

RETURN OLD;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

[Trigger:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo         -- not:  "CREATE OR REPLACE" !
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON some_tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_some_tbl_foo()
```

- Make it an `AFTER` trigger to simplify. A `BEFORE` trigger would have to `RETURN NEW` to make updates work, but `NEW` is not visible in a `DELETE` trigger. So you'd need `IF TG_OP = ...` etc.
- Always provide a target list for persisted `INSERT` statements. This is just as bad in an Oracle trigger.
- You probably have a table with a `serial` column. Just don't mention it in the insert, the next id from the sequence is inserted automatically.

There are numerous code examples here on SO.

Comment: @dacracot: [`CREATE TRIGGER`, there is no `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html).