# Getting error in Postgres trigger creation

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to create this trigger in my PostgresSql environment:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON MYTABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( LENGTH( :NEW.VAL ) > 10 )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20003, 
                             'Cannot exceed 10 chars' );
  END IF;

  IF :NEW.FQN_ID IS NULL THEN
  :NEW.FQN_ID :=
      CASE :NEW.SUBTYPECODE
        WHEN NULL  THEN 'A:'
        WHEN 0     THEN 'B:'
        WHEN 1     THEN 'C:'
        WHEN 2     THEN 'D:'
      ELSE 'Z:' || :NEW.SUBTYPECODE || '::'
      --END || :NEW.OBJECTID;
      END || STRUCTURE_FQNID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
 END IF;
END;
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"  
> LINE 5: BEGIN  
>         ^  
> SQL state: 42601  
> Character: 79
> ```

I think I'm missing something but I can't get it.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your trigger looks like an Oracle trigger to me.  I would suggest you review the documentation on Postgres triggers.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: What's wrong with the manual?

Comment: oops, yes, I'm having poor eye and yes it is Oracle trigger :(. my bad.. sorry. So is there a way / tool to convert oracle triggers into postgres ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536275/migrating-trigger-from-oracle-11g-to-postgresql-8-4

Answer (score 0):

Here are my notes about triggers in several DBMSs: https://github.com/iwis/SQL-notes. I marked the differences between the DBMSs in orange. I think that the notes are quite complete, so you don't have to read about triggers in Postgres documentation.

I see the following changes that need to done in your example:

- Change Oracle `:NEW` to Postgres `NEW`.
- Instead of a `BEGIN ... END` block, write `EXECUTE FUNCTION my_trigger_function();`, where `my_trigger_function` is a function that needs to be created like in [the example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE) given by a_horse_with_no_name.
  This function should return `NEW` in your case - the reason is described [here](https://github.com/iwis/Trigger-notes/blob/main/Other-info.md).

If a more complicated code is fired by a trigger, then you also need to understand the differences between PL/SQL and PL/pgSQL languages. These languages ​​are quite similar, though there are some differences. Your code is simple so the differences are small. It's probably enough to:

- Write Postgres `RETURNS` in the function definition instead of Oracle `RETURN`.
- Write `$$` before `BEGIN`, and `$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;` after `END`.
- Write Postgres `RAISE 'Cannot exceed 10 chars';` instead of Oracle `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Cannot exceed 10 chars');`.

I don't know if sequences work in the same way in PostgreSQL - I haven't read about them yet.

Let me know if my notes are understandable - I'm not sure about it because they are super compact so you need to decipher the markings used by me.